# Pytube module not downloading youtube videoes

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

Hello everyone!,
recently,I've been trying to download YouTube videos using the pytube module.It does indeed work when I use this code.

```
from pytube import YouTube
from sys import argv
from colorama import Fore
import time
URL = argv[1]
a = YouTube(URL)
print(Fore.GREEN + 'video information:')
print('title: ' + a.title)
print('length: '+ str(int(a.length / 60)))
print('downloading file...')
n = time.time()
a = a.streams.get_highest_resolution()
a.download()
v = time.time()
print(str(v-n))
```

But,the thing is,I don;t want the video to download in the highest possible resolution.I want to use other resolutions like 360p , 720p etc.But,when I implement this by writing the code below,

```
from pytube import YouTube
from sys import argv
from colorama import Fore
import time
URL = argv[1]
resolution = argv[2]
a = YouTube(URL)
print(Fore.GREEN + 'video information:')
print('title: ' + a.title)
print('length: '+ str(int(a.length / 60)))
print('downloading file...')
n = time.time()
a = a.streams.get_by_resolution(str(resolution))
a.download()
v = time.time()
print(str(v-n))
```

it gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Desktop/programming/yt.py", line 14, in <module>
    a.download()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
```

I also tried googling this but failed cuz everyone was using the `get_highest_resolution()`
method.
and if you're womedring how I called this script,It was through this command:```
python3 yt.py 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acm6O4WwgBg&list=RDMMacm6O4WwgBg&start_radio=1' , '360p'

```
Can anyone help plz?
```

Comment: How did you call this script?  What did you use in the 2nd argument?  Reason why I ask is that apparently it couldn't get the stream associated with the resolution.  Thus the resulting ```a``` from ```a = a.streams.get_by_resolution(str(resolution))``` is None, I believe.

Comment: I used this command: python3 yt.py 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acm6O4WwgBg&list=RDMMacm6O4WwgBg&start_radio=1' , '360p'

Comment: Is that with or without the ```'```?  Try removing the ```'```  i.e. ```python3 yt.py 'youtube.com/...' 360p```

Comment: still the same error occurs